# Convert percentage to pixel of the height of the window

Tags: jquery, height, carousel

I use Slider pro plugin but it's impossible to set a value for height in percentage.

So I would like to convert percentage in pixel. I need that my slider take 75% of the height of my window.

How to do that ?

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
```

Then I need to put the value (in pixels) for 'height' in the property of my slider :

```
$('#carousel-header').sliderPro({
        width: '100%',
        height: VALUE IN PIXELS,
        aspectRatio: -1,
        buttons: false,
        imageScaleMode: 'cover',
        waitForLayers: true,
        fade: true,
        autoplay: true,
        touchSwipe: false,
        autoplayOnHover: 'none',
        autoScaleLayers: false,
        smallSize: '480'
    });
```

Comment: Wow, really? `$(window).height() * 0.75` comes to mind!

Comment: That return a value in pixel ?

Comment: It would. As for calculation try `($(window).height() / 100) * 75`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `($(window).height() /100)*75`
in place of your value

This should convert it.